# Uncaught TypeError: NaN JavaScript Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have developed a JavaScript countdown timer; also I have a SharePoint list that retrieves the minutes for countdown and its column name is `Koha`

I am retrieving `Koha` and initializing in  a variable; But when I try running the app the countdown timer shows me NaN?

This is how I am retrieving `Koha` field:

```
function Retrieve(){
    currentQuizItem = quizList.getItemById(quizID);
    var quizName;
    context.load(currentQuizItem);

    var koha = currentQuizItem.get_fieldValues()["koha"];

    //even if I try to convert it to number it does not work
    koha = parseInt(Koha);

    alert(koha); // here I can see my value but later when I initialize this var to countdown it says NaN;

}
```

This is my JavaScript countdown timer

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveSec = 60 * koha,   //If I make this 60 * 20 it works and there are 20 min to countdown
    display = document.querySelector('#UItimer');

    startTimer(fiveSec, display);
};
```

Now when I run my app if shown me NaN:NaN instead of showing me timer

please help me

Comment: Check which value is actually stored in Koha. Also I think you have a typo in your question. The `var fiveSec` line ends with ',' instead of ";". Or is it in your code like that?

Comment: It is not the problem `,` elsewhere is the problem

Comment: Yeah I figured it wouldn't be the problem, that's why I didn't post this as an answer @lamnderon :-)

Comment: because I have not solved me problem yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are getting this error since the [`SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907.aspx) is missing. The specified method is mandatory, it *submits the pending query on the server,* without it the line

```
var koha = currentQuizItem.get_fieldValues()["koha"];
```

returns `undefined`.

Here is a generic example for getting list item

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
ctx.load(item);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
      var val = item.get_fieldValues()[fieldName];
      //...     
   },
   function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```